# Creating .PDF from Terminal

Tags: internet, pdf, command-line

it it possible that to make PDF of any **webpage** using any command in Terminal

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider using [wkhtmltopdf](https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) utility.

Example:

```
wkhtmltopdf http://www.google.com google.pdf
```

And yes, it's not installed by default, so you'll need to:

```
sudo apt-get install wkhtmltopdf
```