# How can I print a webpage to a PDF in a single, *continuous* page?

Tags: printing, pdf

I have an ipython notebook that I would like to print without having the page breaks cut through my figures.

Any suggestions?  I tried the "awesome screenshot" extension for chromium, but it was buggy and ended up cutting out half of my page.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try `wkhtmltopdf`, as suggested [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/215734/creating-pdf-from-terminal).

Comment: @Mik, Seems promising!  I'll give it a try (but holy *hell* do they need to come up with a better name!) =D

Comment: @Mik, This seems to print over multiple pages, which exactly the problem I'm trying to avoid.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes you're right, but something like the gnome-photo plugin for shutter, as discussed [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/231757/screenshot-tools-to-capture-scrolling-windows/233779#233779) might be useful, but you would have to convert the image to pdf, as the answer below also mentions this relating to the chrome extension.

Answer (score 2):

I have managed to use `gnome-web-photo` in conjunction with `imagemagick` to produce a decent quality single, tall pdf of a webpage using a single command. You should already have `imagemagick`, but install `gnome-web-photo` with

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-web-photo
```

In this oneliner, `convert` is the program used from the imagemagick package:

```
gnome-web-photo --mode=photo http://www.askubuntu.com --file ask.png && cat ask.png | convert - ask.pdf
```

The tall web page is downloaded by `gnome-web-photo` to file, and can't be piped directly to `convert` without saving it as an image file first. So one way for `convert` to receive that file though the pipe is to concatenate it and then use `convert -` so that the png file is received by `convert` via stdin (denoted as `-`) and then converted to pdf.

However, for the second part of the command you could use `&& convert ask.png ask.pdf` instead of `&& cat ask.png | convert - ask.pdf`, but both take about the same time.

You can use the `--print` option with `gnome-web-photo` to print a webpage to file (i.e. pdf), but it didn't produce a suitable single page result, so the oneliner above is about the best that can be done.

Answer (score 2):

PDF has a defined media size, so you're going to have to do some workarounds:

1. Set up a custom page size in your printer. I have one, TenLetter, which is 215.9 × 2794 mm, or a sheet the length of 10 US letter pages end to end. It doesn't split unless the whole content is longer than ten pages. It's a pain to view (zoom is your friend) or to print, but it doesn't break any images.
2. Manually import the static HTML page into a wordprocessor, and do manual page breaks before the images you don't want split.

Automatic pagination is a hard problem, and most browsers aren't that great at implementing printing support. [CSS Print Profile](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-print/) is one of those great ideas that *almost* works for everyone …

Answer (score 1):

I recently had the same need, and did it in two steps:

1) I used the Chrome Screen Capture Extension (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/screen-capture-by-google/cpngackimfmofbokmjmljamhdncknpmg?hl=en) to capture the page in a png

2) I printed the PNG to a PDF

Comment: this isn't quite doing the trick.  The resulting PDF is an 8.5/11" page and it's impossible to zoom in close enough to see anything other than a blur...